# Is it possible to send messages to an Android application?

Tags: android, send, message

I want to send some info messages to my users or disable my Android application remotely.

I want to know if it is possible to send message (Not SMS) to my android application from my server. It yes how can I do that?

Comment: you need to implement GCM in your application then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former [Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM)](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) (now [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)) is a service that helps developers send data from servers to their applications on Android devices.

Comment: actually, now it is called as GCM

Answer (score 1):

In the past there was [Cloud 2 Device Messaging Frameword C2DM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm). It is superseded by [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use xmpp for that 
Documention Found
xmpp.org/